# How can I fix require statement error at Php?

Tags: php, dompdf

I would like to use DomPdf library for my php function. I installed library with composer. But I have a problem with path of php functions at library. Whenever I deleted Options.php from Dompdf.php I am getting error like *'Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class Options not found'*. But I am writing the require statements, I am taking error like *'Fatal error: Cannot declare class Options, because the name is already in use'*. I am adding below my code. I have general problem with require statement. Can you give me an idea? Thank you in advance..

Dompdf class is

```html
<?php

require 'C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\dompdf\vendor\dompdf\dompdf\src\Options.php';
require 'C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\dompdf\vendor\dompdf\dompdf\src\CanvasFactory.php';


class Dompdf
{
  ...
```

Options class is

```html
<?php

class Options
{
  ..
```

My main index.php is

```html
<?php

    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
    include 'C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\dompdf\vendor\dompdf\dompdf\src\Dompdf.php';

    $dompdf = new Dompdf();
    $dompdf->loadHtml('<h1>DOMPDF Demo</h1><br><p>Hello World !</p>');

    $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream();
        
?>
```

Comment: I think you should provide path from the server root directory not file system path
For example, 
`C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\dompdf\vendor\dompdf\dompdf\src\Options.php` Should be `/dompdf/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/Options.php`

Comment: Composer autoloads for you. `composer require dompdf/dompdf` from the app root directory. Do not include anything else.

Comment: "Whenever I deleted Options.php from Dompdf.php" What? Why are you deleting things from the library files?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're code is in some other directory, let's say it's folder name os`project` in `htdocs` folder and you've installed `DomPdf` in another folder in `htdocs`. So, in your main `index.php` file you simply need to do like this

```php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
require_once dirname(__DIR__).'/dompdf/vendor/autoload.php';

$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml('<h1>DOMPDF Demo</h1><br><p>Hello World !</p>');

$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream();
```

`dirname()` function returns parent's directory path. So, if you know that you've installed library one-level outside then you need to use this function once, If installed library two-level outside from your script in which you want to include it, then you need to use this function twice like this `dirname(dirname(__DIR__))` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the server root directory as the base path and rest of the files should consider as the root `/` in case you are running php on any HTTP server like apache or nginx, in your cases is XAMPP thus apache.

The paths that you include in your php files should either be relative to the current file or should be absolute to the server root.

For example, considering default configuration for your XAMPP,

The following paths are not correct:

```
require 'C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\dompdf\vendor\dompdf\dompdf\src\Options.php';
require 'C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\dompdf\vendor\dompdf\dompdf\src\CanvasFactory.php';

// Considering C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp as root, these Should be 

require '/dompdf/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/Options.php';
require '/dompdf/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/CanvasFactory.php';
```

Similarly in index.php,

```
include 'C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\dompdf\vendor\dompdf\dompdf\src\Dompdf.php';

// Should be

include '/dompdf/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/Dompdf.php';
```

Notice apache follows unix style `/` instead of windows style `\`

If you want to play around with server roots,
you can refer to [apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org) and other resource available on internet

Comment: This is nothing to do with Apache, but Windows directory separators work fine for PHP `include`/`require` statements.